# Awkward brush-like font

Tags: font-identification

This is a capture of an image I did several years ago.

[image: WASA]

I need to find the font used.

**What I am totally sure of :**

- It is a free font

**What I am almost sure of :**

- I got it on Dafont

**What I am not so sure of :**

- I edited the W or the S.

I have been trying to retrieve this font for more than a year without success. Trying involves using all the font identification sites out there* (as you can see the image is optimized for them), entierly browsing several relevant categories on Dafont (hundreds and hundreds of fonts) and downloading FindMyFont software.

Sadly the small amount of letters makes it really difficult to identify, and I obviously don't have any other images with other letters.

Now I think the only option left is to ask people. I would be very thankful to the person who would find this font.

---

*WhatTheFont, Identifont (basic quizz, similar font with Skippy Sharp, unusual features), WhatFontIs, MatchCreator, FontEdge, Photoshop font match.

Comment: Is that the highest resolution image you have?

Comment: @Cai Sadly, yes it is...

Comment: it looks like kinda hand drawn.